# jQuery / JavaScript not working on sub-pages on a jQuery Mobile enabled webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm have a image in the header of my jQuery Mobile website that I resize automaticly so it fills the screen. On my page there is a sub-page for loggin in users. But on this page the resizing of the image will not work.

As I'm googling for a solution I already found out it is caused by jQuery Mobile that only allows jQuery to work inside the first data-role="page" div. But as I'm trying each solution, none of them seem to will work.

Can you guys help me find the solution?

My code (in a short copy/paste example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>WHY DON'T YOU WORK?</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onresize = function (event) {
                resizeimage();
            }
            window.onload = function (event) {
                resizeimage();
            }            
            function resizeimage() {
                var img = document.getElementById('headerimage');

                var oldwidth = img.naturalWidth;
                var oldheight = img.naturalHeight;

                var newwidth = $(window).width();
                var newheight = oldheight / oldwidth * newwidth;

                img.width = newwidth;
                img.height = newheight;     
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="PageDiv" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="FrontPage">

            <div class="HeaderDiv" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <img id="headerimage" name="headerimage" src="images/PSO_Banner_960x89.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="ContentDiv" data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                CONTENT #1
                <a href="#LoginPage">LoginPage</a>
            </div>

            <div class="FooterDiv" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="PageDiv" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="LoginPage">

            <div class="HeaderDiv" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <img id="headerimage" name="headerimage" src="images/PSO_Banner_960x89.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="ContentDiv" data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                CONTENT #2
                <a href="#FrontPage">FrontPage</a>
            </div>

            <div class="FooterDiv" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Still searching for the solution...

Comment: Code suggestion: `$(window).on('load resize', resizeimage)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First don't mix vanilla javascript and jQuery.

Your problem is that you have 2 pages with 2 same header pictures. Bot of them are loaded into the DOM and you function is always accessing the first one, picture in your first page.

You will need a little bit of jQuery and jQuery Mobile to make this work.

Instead of this:

```
    var img = document.getElementById('headerimage');
```

use this:

```
    var img = $.mobile.activePage.find('#headerimage');
```

**EDIT :**

Working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>WHY DON'T YOU WORK?</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onresize = function (event) {
                resizeimage();
            }

            window.onload = function (event) {
                resizeimage();
            }    

            $(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){ 
                resizeimage();       
            });

            function resizeimage() {
                var img = $.mobile.activePage.find('#headerimage');//document.getElementById('headerimage');

                var oldwidth = img.naturalWidth;
                var oldheight = img.naturalHeight;

                var newwidth = $(window).width();
                var newheight = oldheight / oldwidth * newwidth;

                img.width(newwidth);
                img.height(newheight); 

                $(window).trigger( "throttledresize" );             
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="PageDiv" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="FrontPage">

            <div class="HeaderDiv" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <img id="headerimage" name="headerimage" src="http://www.azhumane.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/AHS025_mastSM_21-11.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="ContentDiv" data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                CONTENT #1
                <a href="#LoginPage">LoginPage</a>
            </div>

            <div class="FooterDiv" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h3>FOOTER</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="PageDiv" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="LoginPage">

            <div class="HeaderDiv" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <img id="headerimage" name="headerimage" src="http://www.azhumane.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/AHS025_mastSM_21-11.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="ContentDiv" data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                CONTENT #2
                <a href="#FrontPage">FrontPage</a>
            </div>

            <div class="FooterDiv" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h3>FOOTER</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't agree with the first statement, but the second is dead on. Would be better with an example of how to fix this with using classes instead and the pageInit event.

Comment: Ok first reason is esthetic and subjective. His solution is in jQuery Mobile $.mobile.activePage selector.

Comment: There's only one other issue, the resizeImage method will need to also be called on pageInit as pageInit will not trigger a window load or a resize event.

Comment: Guys, this solution is not working, I changed the code and the header is not resizing anymore, also on the first page.

Comment: This is because you are still using javascript like nothing had happened. When you finally set the height and width you are doing it like you would do to classic javascript object. It must be done like it is a jQuery object.